# How to display a particular word in bold using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to display a particular word in bold using jquery.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
            var user = $('#username').val();
            if (response.d == 1) {


                $('#result').text(user + ' already Exists');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', true);

            } else {
                $('#result').text('Username '+user +' Ok');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', false);
            }


        }
```

Here i want to make the username(user) to be bold ,rest of the sentence must be normal.Is it possible by using jquery?

Comment: what tag does #result point to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `html` instead of `text`

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    var user = $('#username').val();
    if (response.d == 1) {
        $('#result').html('<b>' + user + '</b> already Exists');
        $('#Button1').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#result').html('Username <b>' + user + '</b> Ok');
        $('#Button1').attr('disabled', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of $('#Button1').attr('disabled', false);, I'd use removeAttr('disabled'). But that's a matter of preference, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

I peronally prefer using a own span-tag to highlight the username.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
            var user = $('#username').val();
            if (response.d == 1) {


                $('#result').html('<span id="user">' + user + '</span> already Exists');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', true);

            } else {
                $('#result').html('Username <span id="user">'+user +'</span> Ok');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', false);
            }

            $('#user').css('font-weight', 'bold');

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('#result').html('<strong>'+user+'</strong>' + ' already Exists');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by changing `.text()` to `.html()` and passing a valid chunk of html, e.g.:

```
$('#result').html('<strong>' + user + '</strong> already Exists');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.css()` to set the attribut font-weight to bold.
Example : `$('#mytext').css('font-weight', 'bold')`

Answer (score 1):

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
            var user = $('#username').val();
            if (response.d == 1) {


                $('#result').html('<strong>' + user + '</strong> already Exists');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', true);

            } else {
                $('#result').html('Username <strong>'+user +'</strong> Ok');
                $('#Button1').attr('disabled', false);
            }


        }
```

this should do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#resut').html("Hello " + "<span class='bold'>" + user  +"</span>");
```